# How to disable hibernate generated comments (after reverse engineer a database)?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-tools

How to remove this comment generated by Hibernate:

```
package com.mypackage.db.entity;

// Generated Oct 20, 2015 4:03:57 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1.Final

import ...
```

The comment appears every time I try to reverse engineer a database model. I've also tried to override some methods like `tableToClassName` and `tableToMetaAttributes` using my own renaming strategy by extending to the `DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy` but these comments still appear in my entity classes.

I would like to know how these comments can be disabled/removed when generating the entity classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to read the documentation: [Controlling POJO Codegeneration](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/codegen.html)

There is an example on how to change a generation template. In your case this would be `pojo/Pojo.ftl`.

So create a custom template directory (I call it `CUSTOM_TEMPLATES`) and copy `hibernate-tools.jar/pojo/Pojo.ftl` to `CUSTOM_TEMPLATES/pojo/Pojo.ftl`. Change the file and remove the line

```
// Generated ${date} by Hibernate Tools ${version}
```

All you need to do now is to specify the custom template directory for the tool:

```
<hibernatetool ... templatepath="CUSTOM_TEMPLATES">
```